# Logstash to merge unstructured log lines to one event

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I have my log format like this

```
[23:59:43] TYPE[student03]
[23:59:43] Write Ack!
[23:59:43] <application><status>Active</status></application>
[23:59:43] --------PushToFile Start--------
[23:59:43] --------PushToFile Name --------
[23:59:43] --------PushToFile End--------
[23:59:47] --------on parser--------
[23:59:47] ClientIPAddress > 123.12.123.2
[23:59:43] TYPE[student04]
[23:59:43] Write Ack!
[23:59:43] FGHSFHG3453D56HJ3456FJ372GJ1387FFKJH
[23:59:43] --------PushToFile Start--------
[23:59:43] --------PushToFile Name --------
[23:59:43] --------PushToFile End--------
[23:59:47] --------on parser--------
[23:59:47] ClientIPAddress > 123.12.123.2
[23:59:43] TYPE[student03]
[23:59:43] Write Ack!
[23:59:43] FGHSFHG3453D56HJ3456FJ372GJ1387FFKJH
[23:59:43] --------PushToFile Start--------
[23:59:43] --------PushToFile Name --------
[23:59:43] --------PushToFile End--------
[23:59:47] --------on parser--------
[23:59:47] ClientIPAddress > 123.12.123.2
```

I want to parse these logs to get only TYPE[student03] and the Status of the student. I am dropping the remaining lines with lostash filters. Now I need the TYPE and status as a single event so that I can send it to rabbitmq as a single message like

`[23:59:43]-student03-<application><status>Active</status></application>`

How can we achieve this with aggregate filters? I tried aggregate filters. But, I think we need the same pattern in both log lines to merge with aggregate. or any alternatives for this

Please help!

My logstash configuration file

```
    beats {
     port => 5044
   }
}
filter {

  if ([message] =~ "Write Ack!"){
   drop{}
  }
  else if ([message] =~ "PushToFile Start"){
    drop{}
  }
  else if ([message] =~ "PushToFile Name"){
    drop{}
  }
  else if ([message] =~ "PushToFile End"){
    drop{}
  }
  else if ([message] =~ "on parser"){
     drop{}
  }  
  else if ([message] =~ "ClientIPAddress") {
    drop { }
  }                     
}
output {
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: You are right, to use the aggregate filter you need a common identifier in both lines. If your information blocks always start with `TYPE` you can then use multiline on filebeat or logstash to get everything between `TYPE` and `ClientIPAddress` as one single event and then use other filters to keep only parse your message. Please share more of your log file to see what can be done.

Comment: @leandrojmp I updated my question to have more log. With multiline how can I remove the unnecessary lines of as its coming as a single event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **Grok filter**(see below) to parse only the two required lines and later use the below **Ruby filter** to do the necessary string operations and save the final message in a field and use it.

**Grok filter**

```
grok{
    match => {"message" => "%{TIME}] TYPE.%{GREEDYDATA:STATUS}."}
    match => {"message" => "%{TIME}] <application><status>Active</status></application>"}
    }
if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags]{drop{}}
```

**Ruby filter**

```
ruby{
    code => "
        if event.get('STATUS')
            @save_status = event.get('STATUS')
            event.cancel()
        else
            event.set('final_message', event.get('message').sub(' ', '-'+@save_status+'-'))
        end
    "
}
```

Please note that this works only if your logs come in sequence.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. But, I want to take student type also as part of the final message. and also this line <application><status>Active</status></application> is not common for all events. So, I wanted an entire line to be as part of the final message. It may be an XML, JSON, alphanumeric. I updated my question.

Comment: Thank you. With the above approach, I write the configuration and it worked for me. One thing as in my logs I am getting only Timestamp not the data. Can we append the date to the final message in ruby code? I tried multiple ways to append but nothing worked.

Comment: I can't see any date in your log files. It's just the time filed at the start. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Yes, it's just a timestamp. I want to append the date dynamically to each message.

Comment: Append the file creation date to the file name and then you can extract the same and add it in the Grok filter using ```match => "path"``` option

Comment: Yea. But, here the input plugin is file beats right? Not the file path